# Make click event of label propagate

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have following html code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<label style="position:absolute;">foo1</label>
<label style="position:absolute;">foo2</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("label").on("click",function(){
        console.log("Jquery",$(this).html());
    })
    d3.selectAll("label").on("click",function(){
        console.log("D3",d3.select(this).html());
    })
</script>
```

Two labels are overlapped. When I click the label, only "foo2" is printed. 
I want both foo1 and foo2 received the click event and the event seems stopped by foo2.

I found there are Event.stopPropagation() but no Event.startPropagation().
How can I make the event propagate?

Comment: You misunderstood [event propagation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#h-event-flow).

Comment: I got what you mean. Is it possible for one click event to trigger both elements?